# Prenex normal form question right?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Just to see if I'm on the right track here, I did this sample problem in my book which unfortunately has no answers. It is asking to find an equivalent formula in prenex normal form for this formula...

$$\forall xX=0\lor(\neg\exists z(x+z=x))$$

After some working I got to this answer...

$$\forall z(\forall xX=0\lor\neg(x+z=x))$$

Is this right?

Comment: Apart from the use of parentheses, it is OK. There was no particular reason to drag $\forall z$ to the very front, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Really? I think my knowledge of PNF might be questionable in that case. I thought the quantifiers have to be at the start?

Comment: They are almost at the front, apart from the wonky use of parentheses that I pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, cheers!

But, from the looks of it, it is important to realise that you did the following:

\begin{align}
\forall x(x =0 \lor (\neg\exists z(x+z=x))) &\iff \forall x(x=0\lor (\forall z \neg (x+z=x)))\\
&\iff \forall x(\forall z(x = 0\lor \neg(x+z=x)))\\
&\iff \forall z(\forall x(x=0\lor \neg(x+z=x)))
\end{align}

i.e., the last step is not necessary. Now if you went from the second to the fourth expression in one go, you'd be mistaken in general -- particularly if it were $\exists x$ rather than $\forall x$.

It is only warranted to widen the scope of a quantification over $\lor$ or $\land$ (provided the other expression is free in the quantified variable). It is in general **not** warranted to widen the scope of a quantifier over another quantification: $\forall x \exists y (x=y)$ is not equivalent to $\exists y \forall x (x=y)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand now :)

Comment: Just one question, in the final answer, is the first open bracket and the matching last closed bracket necessary? Ie, is this acceptable? \begin{align}
\forall x \forall z(x=0\lor \neg(x+z=x))
\end{align}

Comment: That's fine. In principle you should have parentheses around $x=0$, but one is informally allowed to leave out parentheses when their absence does not impair understandability.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't want to be a bother, just want to check to see if I got the hang of it. I tried this question: $$\exists x\neg P(x) \implies \neg \forall x(P(x)) $$ and I got this answer: $$\forall x \exists y(P(x) \lor \neg P(y))$$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.